# ffmpeg loop move left right video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to move a small video from left to right and then vice versa, continue until this video end, inside a larger video with `ffmpeg`
See the picture below.

Can someone please guide me with a code. Thank you very much.

**move video from left to right and vice versa:**
[image: move video from left to right and vice versa]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i large.mp4 -i small.mp4
  -filter_complex overlay=x='(W-w)*(T/2-abs(mod(t,T)-T/2))/(T/2)':y=H-h-20 out.mp4
```

T is the period of the oscillation i.e. the time it takes for the video to return to the starting position.

e.g. with period T = 6s

```
ffmpeg -i large.mp4 -i small.mp4
  -filter_complex overlay=x='(W-w)*(6/2-abs(mod(t,6)-6/2))/(6/2)':y=H-h-20 out.mp4
```

`W-w` represents the ending position -- attained at half the period. Since the height is fixed, I've put in an arbitrary value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it give the error: No such filter: '6)-6/2))/(6/2):y'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: You'll need to escape the `,` i.e. `\,`